# Targets seem to be building in the wrong order when building Wix Custom Action under TeamCity

Tags: build, wix, teamcity, custom-action

I'm having problems getting my CI build to work under TeamCity. I've got similar projects that build OK, so I don;t think it is a TeamCity problem per se, but I've looked at this so much I'm starting to go code blind and I fear I may be missing the obvious. I would appreciate another perspective.

The project I'm working on (an ASCOM driver) has a Wix setup project and a managed custom action. The custom action has a unit test project that uses MSpec. This all builds fine on my workstation, the tests run and pass, all good. On TeamCity, the solution will not even compile. I welcome the fact that TeamCity may have highlighted a weakness in my build, but I can't understand what's going on here.

What *appears* to be happening is that the build is deleting one of the project outputs (the Wix custom action) during the build, which means that a subsequent project that references it fails to build. Here's some edited highlights from the log output:

The setup projects startsto build...

```
715 [01:21:20]:                             [MSBuild] Product Setup\Product Setup.wixproj: Build target: Rebuild (11s)
716 [01:21:20]:                                 [Product Setup\Product Setup.wixproj] CoreClean
717 [01:21:20]:                                     [CoreClean] Delete
[...]
```

Then it resolves references and notices that the Custom Action project needs to be built...

```
729 [01:21:20]:                                 [Product Setup\Product Setup.wixproj] ResolveProjectReferences (2s)
730 [01:21:21]:                                     [ResolveProjectReferences] MSBuild (2s)
731 [01:21:21]:                                         [MSBuild] Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj: Build default targets (2s)
732 [01:21:21]:                                             [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj] CheckPrerequisites
733 [01:21:21]:                                             [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj] RestorePackages
```

Then the Custom Action project builds and the CA assembly gets packaged and the output copied to the output directory...

```
739 [01:21:21]:                                                 [CoreCompile] Csc
740 [01:21:21]:                                                     [Csc] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva- /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Astrometry.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Attributes.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Controls.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DeviceInterfaces.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DriverAccess.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Exceptions.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.SettingsProvider.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Utilities.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\DTF-Unofficial.3.6.2928\lib\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\bin\Debug\CompanyTools.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\TiGra.Diagnostics.1.1.57\lib\net35\TiGra.Diagnostics.dll /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /out:obj\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll /target:library /utf8output CustomAction.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs SetupTraceListener.cs
741 [01:21:21]:                                                     [Csc] CustomAction.cs(28, 23): warning CS0169: The field 'Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.CustomActions.driverId' is never used
742 [01:21:21]:                                                     [Csc] CustomAction.cs(29, 23): warning CS0169: The field 'Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.CustomActions.driverName' is never used
743 [01:21:21]:                                             [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj] PackCustomAction (1s)
744 [01:21:21]:                                                 [PackCustomAction] Exec (1s)
745 [01:21:21]:                                                     [Exec] "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\..\sdk\MakeSfxCA.exe" "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\obj\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.CA.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\..\sdk\x86\SfxCA.dll" "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\obj\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll" "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Astrometry.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Attributes.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Controls.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DeviceInterfaces.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DriverAccess.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Exceptions.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.SettingsProvider.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Utilities.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\DTF-Unofficial.3.6.2928\lib\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\bin\Debug\CompanyTools.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\TiGra.Diagnostics.1.1.57\lib\net35\TiGra.Diagnostics.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Internal.Extensions.dll;C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\CustomAction.config"
```

The CA build completed and the Setup build resumes:

```
803 [01:21:23]:                                 [Product Setup\Product Setup.wixproj] Compile (1s)
804 [01:21:23]:                                     [Compile] Candle (1s)
805 [01:21:23]:                                         [Candle] C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\candle.exe -dDebug -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*" -dSolutionDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=Product.sln -dSolutionName=Product -dSolutionPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product.sln -dConfiguration=Debug -dOutDir=bin\Debug-x86\ -dPlatform=x86 -d"ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Setup\\" -dProjectExt=.wixproj -d"ProjectFileName=Product Setup.wixproj" -d"ProjectName=Product Setup" -d"ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Setup\Product Setup.wixproj" -d"TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Setup\bin\Debug-x86\\" -dTargetExt=.msi -d"TargetFileName=Product Setup.msi" -d"TargetName=Product Setup" -d"TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Setup\bin\Debug-x86\Product Setup.msi" -dDeviceType1.Configuration=Debug -d"DeviceType1.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dDeviceType1.Platform=AnyCPU -dDeviceType1.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\ -dDeviceType1.ProjectExt=.csproj -dDeviceType1.ProjectFileName=DeviceType1.csproj -dDeviceType1.ProjectName=DeviceType1 -dDeviceType1.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\DeviceType1.csproj -dDeviceType1.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\bin\Debug\ -dDeviceType1.TargetExt=.dll -dDeviceType1.TargetFileName=ASCOM.Product.DeviceType.dll -dDeviceType1.TargetName=ASCOM.Product.DeviceType -dDeviceType1.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\bin\Debug\ASCOM.Product.DeviceType.dll -dProductCommander.Configuration=Debug -d"ProductCommander.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dProductCommander.Platform=AnyCPU -d"ProductCommander.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Commander\\" -dProductCommander.ProjectExt=.csproj -dProductCommander.ProjectFileName=ProductCommander.csproj -dProductCommander.ProjectName=ProductCommander -d"ProductCommander.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Commander\ProductCommander.csproj" -d"ProductCommander.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Commander\bin\Debug\\" -dProductCommander.TargetExt=.exe -d"ProductCommander.TargetFileName=Product Commander.exe" -d"ProductCommander.TargetName=Product Commander" -d"ProductCommander.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Commander\bin\Debug\Product Commander.exe" -dProductServer.Configuration=Debug -d"ProductServer.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dProductServer.Platform=AnyCPU -d"ProductServer.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Server\\" -dProductServer.ProjectExt=.csproj -dProductServer.ProjectFileName=ProductServer.csproj -dProductServer.ProjectName=ProductServer -d"ProductServer.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Server\ProductServer.csproj" -d"ProductServer.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Server\bin\Debug\\" -dProductServer.TargetExt=.exe -dProductServer.TargetFileName=ASCOM.Product.exe -dProductServer.TargetName=ASCOM.Product -d"ProductServer.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Product Server\bin\Debug\ASCOM.Product.exe" -dCompanyTools.Configuration=Debug -d"CompanyTools.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dCompanyTools.Platform=AnyCPU -dCompanyTools.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\ -dCompanyTools.ProjectExt=.csproj -dCompanyTools.ProjectFileName=CompanyTools.csproj -dCompanyTools.ProjectName=CompanyTools -dCompanyTools.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\CompanyTools.csproj -dCompanyTools.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\bin\Debug\ -dCompanyTools.TargetExt=.dll -dCompanyTools.TargetFileName=CompanyTools.dll -dCompanyTools.TargetName=CompanyTools -dCompanyTools.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\bin\Debug\CompanyTools.dll -dDeviceType1.Configuration=Debug -d"DeviceType1.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dDeviceType1.Platform=AnyCPU -dDeviceType1.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\ -dDeviceType1.ProjectExt=.csproj -dDeviceType1.ProjectFileName=DeviceType1.csproj -dDeviceType1.ProjectName=DeviceType1 -dDeviceType1.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\DeviceType1.csproj -dDeviceType1.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\bin\Debug\ -dDeviceType1.TargetExt=.dll -dDeviceType1.TargetFileName=ASCOM.Product.DeviceType.dll -dDeviceType1.TargetName=ASCOM.Product.DeviceType -dDeviceType1.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\DeviceType1\bin\Debug\ASCOM.Product.DeviceType.dll -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Configuration=Debug -d"Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Platform=AnyCPU -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.ProjectDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\ -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.ProjectExt=.csproj -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.ProjectFileName=Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.ProjectName=Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.ProjectPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.TargetDir=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\ -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.TargetExt=.dll -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.TargetFileName=Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.TargetName=Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles -dWix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.TargetPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll -out obj\Debug\ -arch x86 -ext ..\Lib\Wix\WixNetFxExtension.dll -ext ..\Lib\Wix\WixUIExtension.dll AscomDeviceProfileData.wxs CommanderApp.wxs DeviceTypeDriver.wxs LocalServer.wxs Product.wxs DeviceTypeDriver.wxs
806 [01:21:24]:                                         [Candle] Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 3.7.1224.0
```

Now here's where it all goes awry. The Custom Action project goes on to try to rebuild and does a CoreClean action:

```
827 [01:21:32]:                             [MSBuild] Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj: Build target: Rebuild
828 [01:21:32]:                                 [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj] CleanCustomAction
829 [01:21:32]:                                     [CleanCustomAction] Delete
830 [01:21:32]:                                         [Delete] Deleting file "obj\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.CA.dll".
831 [01:21:32]:                                 [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.csproj] CoreClean
832 [01:21:32]:                                     [CoreClean] Delete
```

Then shortly after that, the MSpec unit test project tries to build, and can't find the outputs from the Custom Action project.

907 [01:21:33]:                                 [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications.csproj] ResolveAssemblyReferences
908 [01:21:33]:                                     [ResolveAssemblyReferences] ResolveAssemblyReference
909 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference] Primary reference "Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles".
910 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference]     Could not find dependent files. Expected file "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll" does not exist.
911 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference]     Could not find dependent files. Expected file "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll" does not exist.
912 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference]     Resolved file path is "C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll".
913 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference]     Reference found at search path location "".
914 [01:21:33]:                                         [ResolveAssemblyReference]     The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "".
915 [01:21:33]:                                 [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications.csproj] CoreCompile
916 [01:21:33]:                                     [CoreCompile] Csc
917 [01:21:33]:                                         [Csc] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva- /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Astrometry.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Attributes.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Controls.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DeviceInterfaces.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.DriverAccess.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Exceptions.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.SettingsProvider.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\ASCOM.Platform.6.0.2.1\lib\net35\ASCOM.Utilities.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\FakeItEasy.1.13.1\lib\net35\FakeItEasy.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\packages\Machine.Specifications.0.5.14\lib\net20\Machine.Specifications.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\CompanyTools\bin\Debug\CompanyTools.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications.dll /target:library /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs RegisterAscomDeviceProfilesSpecs.cs
918 [01:21:33]:                                         [Csc] CSC error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\BuildAgent\work\bf752c89b3da5535\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles\bin\Debug\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.dll' could not be found
919 [01:21:33]:                                 [Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications.csproj] Project Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications\Wix.RegisterAscomDeviceProfiles.Specifications.csproj failed.

I can't figure out why things appear to be happening all out of order on the build server. This all builds happily within Visual Studio on my workstation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. If you solved this, it would be awesome to find out how.

Comment: I'm really sorry - we resolved the problem _somehow_ but I honestly can't remember how. Shame on me for not updating my questing with an answer. Normally it's a problem with the build configuration...

Comment: Finally figured it out after some hours. My case was unique, two DLLs I needed coming from a Nuget package pulled in in the previous step were being deleted by team city. I changed from "Rebuild" (Clean+Build) to "Build" and this stopped the dll from being deleted. The overall process is still a Clean build because I have the checkbox for clean build on the overall project. Now the DLLs are left in and the wix build step can see them.

Comment: @RobertNoack I had an issue using WiX with 2 setup projects (x86 and x64) The x64 would fail as it tried to build itself and clean it's own dependencies. Changing TeamCity to Build instead of Rebuild fixed the issue. [Also this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4029891/265419)

Comment: @tim-long you should add an answer here and close this question.

Comment: @JasonHughes - I wish I could, but as I said in my previous comment, I really can't remember how it was resolved.

Comment: I agree this isn't TeamCity-specific. I can reproduce the problem with a solution just by calling `msbuild /t:Rebuild`

Comment: If anyone can reproduce this in a public solution, please add more info to an issue I've logged here - https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5129

Answer (score 0):

Set teamcity.msbuild.generateWrappingScript to false

Can be found here: [MSBuild - Implementation notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/MSBuild)

> **Implementation notes**
>
> MSBuild runner generates an MSBuild script that includes user's script. This script is used to add TeamCity provided msbuild tasks. Your MSBuild script will be included with the <Import> task. If you specified a Visual Studio solution file, it will be called from the <MSBuild> task. To disable it, set teamcity.msbuild.generateWrappingScript to false.